# Replicate Integrations after sandbox refresh

Tags: sandbox, refresh

I have a full sandbox that has a few integrations with 3rd party vendors like lexis nexis, onespan, mainframe core(informatica updates), community portal. We want to refresh the SB from prod and then ensure these integrations are rewired and work as before. Can you advise on which is the easiest way to make a copy before refresh and be able to get those settings back after refresh. What would need be done on my side vs other vendors side. Thoughts appreciated !

Comment: There is no single answer for this, since some integrations require actions on external system side to re-establish the connection or do special configuration, while others may require manual changes to settings based on domain name et.c

Answer (score 0):

As a best practices, It is suggested to document existing integrations with external systems like lexis nexis, onespan, mainframe core etc., and
make sure the endpoint URLs, credentials, etc. are all updated. These values are typically saved in the Custom Settings, Custom Metadata Types, and Named Credentials.

Below are few check points.

- What are the integration channels in place.
- What are the credentials used.
- Is the Connected App used.
- Which Salesforce API is used.
- How would two-side teams collaborate in the entire refreshing time
  period.
- How to switch the integration endpoint from production to test
  environment.

Also, check [Sandbox Setup Considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_sandbox_implementation_tips.htm&type=5) and you might have few limitations like [Copying Connected Apps setting](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdcBWUAZ/copying-connected-apps-setting-information-as-part-of-sandbox-refresh) etc.,  and you need to have post migration activities document checklist.

Check sandbox refresh best practices [here](https://salesforceway.com/blog/salesforce-sandbox-refresh-best-practices/).

There are few good 3rd party tools like Gearset, Flosum, Autorabit, Copado, Bluecanvas etc., to automate salesforce deployment activities on point and click interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response